# MaterialButton is appearing weird on preview and on device as well

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

I am using `MaterialButton` but it is not appearing correctly.

Here is the code I am using

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/verifyOTP"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Verify OTP"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

Here is current display

[image]

This is the dependency I am using

```
'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
```

This is the behavior I am expecting

[image]

Please help me how to resolve this problem.

**Note:** `Button` is working fine only `MaterialButton` is not working correctly

Comment: what is the result expected ?

Comment: A normal material button.

Comment: why dont you use button and use some material design styling ?

Comment: Because Material Button is by default styled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add style attribute to your MaterialButton declaration :

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
android:id="@+id/verifyOTP"
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="20dp"
android:text="..."/>
```

Comment: Tried but not working

Comment: what is the dependency implemented ?

Comment: Updated in question

Comment: did you tried to define the height with some size ex : 80dp ?

Comment: Check the question again, the height is not giving me my desired behavior

Comment: because you set wrap content so it will fit the text height , try to set it at 80 dp

Comment: well it do increase the height but the other styling is not performed

Comment: Well as I said I simple Button is working so I have did that but I want to know why is Material Button not working

Comment: set wrap content for both witdh and height and add padding . check my edit

Comment: Well It s increasing the size but the ripple affect and text is still same